# Finding coefficient of containers

Tags: probability

My question is a real problem in bioinformatics of polyploids. I tried to say it as a probabilities problem (sorry if is written so bad):

Assume we have n containers with fixed coefficients. each container has four balls red, green, blue and black. In each round we take out a ball from each of n containers and give each ball a value as much as the coefficient of its container.

How can we find the number of containers (n) using just values of 4 colors obtained in some (may be infinite) rounds?

> this is an example (we have 3 containers with respectively 4,7,9
>   coefficient):
>
> Round one: Green, Green, Red; so we have: Green=11, Red=9
>
> Round two: Red, Blue, Green: so we have: Red=4, Blue=7, Green=9
>
> and so on many rounds, and finally we have a table like this:
>
> Green  Red  Blue  Black
>
> 11  9  0  0
>
> 9 4 7 0
>
> 0 9 11 0
>
> 0 0 0 20
>
> 0 13 0 7
>
> Based on this data what is the number of containers? and what is their
>   coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From any row you get the sum of the coefficients is $20$.  Now you want to find the smallest multiset of numbers that can get all the sums you have.  The sums are $4,7,9,11,13,20$.  Start from the smallest.  You see a $4$ so unless there are smaller coefficients that always were paired with another bin there must be a bin with $4$.  The next smallest is $7$ and if there were not a $7$ you would expect to see a $3$ to go with the $4$, so you believe there is a $7$.  Similarly for $9$, you would expect a $2$ or $3$ if the $9$ were a sum of two balls, so you think you have a $9$.  You now have enough numbers to explain all the observations, so you claim there are three bins $4,7,9$.  You can't be sure-it could be that there are $20$ bins all numbered $1$ and the random draws always came out in groups of $4,7,9$.  The more data you take, the more sure you are that there are no bins that are always paired with another.  If there are four colors and $n$ bins, the chance a given bin is alone on one draw is $(\frac 34)^{n-1}$.  If you make $k$ draws, the chance you have never seen a given bin alone is $\left(1-(\frac 34)^{n-1}\right)^k$.  If you make $k$ high enough, this chance will be quite low and it will be easy to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you. very useful answer. ross-millikan & @jean-marie in this problem If the sum of coefficients have some errors (in the current example between 17 to 23 while I know that 20 is correct sum of coefficients) what is the best approach to normal such errors and their effect on final decision?

Answer (score 1):

A remark that can be the beginning of a solution: we can anticipate the different result occurences by associating to your "game" the following polynomial (I have retained your first example) with as many letters as there are colors:

$$\underbrace{(r^4+g^4+b^4)}_{\text{1st container}}\underbrace{(r^7+g^7+b^7)}_{\text{2nd container}}\underbrace{(r^9+g^9+b^9)}_{\text{3rd container}}$$

which, expanded, gives all occurences:

$$b^{20} + b^{16}\,g^4 + 
  b^{13}\,g^7 + b^{11}\,g^9 + 
  b^9\,g^{11} + b^7\,g^{13} + 
  b^4\,g^{16} + g^{20} + 
  b^{16}\,r^4 + 
  b^9\,g^7\,r^4 + 
  b^7\,g^9\,r^4 + 
  g^{16}\,r^4 + b^{13}\,r^7 + 
  b^9\,g^4\,r^7 + 
  b^4\,g^9\,r^7 + 
  g^{13}\,r^7 + b^{11}\,r^9 + 
  b^7\,g^4\,r^9 + 
  b^4\,g^7\,r^9 + 
  g^{11}\,r^9 + b^9\,r^{11} + 
  g^9\,r^{11} + b^7\,r^{13} + 
  g^7\,r^{13} + b^4\,r^{16} + 
  g^4\,r^{16} + r^{20}$$
for example, the second term "means" 16 associated with blue and 4 associated with green. Here each kind of term has been met once.

But if we expand for example :

$$\underbrace{(r+g+b)}_{\text{1st container}}\underbrace{(r^2+g^2+b^2)}_{\text{2nd container}}\underbrace{(r^3+g^3+b^3)}_{\text{3rd container}}\underbrace{(r^4+g^4+b^4)}_{\text{4th container}}$$

one finds $$b^{10} + b^9\,g + b^8\,g^2 + 
  2\,b^7\,g^3 + 2\,b^6\,g^4 + 
  2\,b^5\,g^5 + \cdots$$

with many coefficients 2.

If you have many many results, you can try to match the statistics you obtain with the theoretical coefficients, in the different cases that may occur (hypothesis : 3 containers, hypothesis 4 containers, etc. with such and such coefficients)

Honestly, I don't know if the way I have shown is practical or leads to a combinatorial explosion: it is the maximum I can say with the data you have provided.

Comment: Thank you. I learned so much. As you and Ross mentioned, I think this problem have not an exact answer and need some statistics...